# How to get random forest regression performance output in Python like that produced in R?

Tags: python, r, random-forest

In R, I can easily get the performance of a random forest like the following.
How can I get the similar stuff in Python easily? Thanks a lot.

```
Summary of the Random Forest Model
==================================

Number of observations used to build the model: 35
Missing value imputation is active.

Call:
 randomForest(formula = rank ~ .,
              data = crs$dataset[crs$sample, c(crs$input, crs$target)],
              ntree = 500, mtry = 3, importance = TRUE, replace = FALSE, na.action = na.roughfix)

               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

          Mean of squared residuals: 5.578147
                    % Var explained: 97.22

Variable Importance
```

Comment: You may want to move your question to http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check out sklearn, the random forest (and most of the other machine learning) implementation has the variable importance / etc that you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Here there is a simple example using sklearn random forest . http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier

You can easily get the values that you are looking for.
In this example we are using an input matrix X with 2 variables and a binary output y.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

fr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, oob_score=True).fit(X, y)

fr.n_estimators
Out[10]: 100

fr.oob_decision_function_
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0.14285714,  0.85714286],
       [ 0.86666667,  0.13333333],
       [ 0.02631579,  0.97368421],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.97826087,  0.02173913],
       [ 0.97826087,  0.02173913],
       [ 0.20512821,  0.79487179],
       [ 0.97368421,  0.02631579],
       [ 0.77777778,  0.22222222],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.52380952,  0.47619048],
       [ 0.43243243,  0.56756757],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.05714286,  0.94285714],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.76470588,  0.23529412],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.95454545,  0.04545455],
       [ 0.9       ,  0.1       ],
       [ 0.02222222,  0.97777778],
       [ 0.875     ,  0.125     ],
       [ 0.02857143,  0.97142857],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.58823529,  0.41176471],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.20512821,  0.79487179],
       [ 0.97435897,  0.02564103],
       [ 0.91176471,  0.08823529],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.30232558,  0.69767442],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.94444444,  0.05555556],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.075     ,  0.925     ],
       [ 0.05263158,  0.94736842],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.02702703,  0.97297297],
       [ 0.91176471,  0.08823529],
       [ 0.43243243,  0.56756757],
       [ 0.08333333,  0.91666667],
       [ 0.10526316,  0.89473684],
       [ 0.93548387,  0.06451613],
       [ 0.02857143,  0.97142857],
       [ 0.53658537,  0.46341463],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.66666667,  0.33333333],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.55555556,  0.44444444],
       [ 0.96666667,  0.03333333],
       [ 0.97142857,  0.02857143],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.05882353,  0.94117647],
       [ 0.94594595,  0.05405405],
       [ 0.11904762,  0.88095238],
       [ 0.92307692,  0.07692308],
       [ 0.69767442,  0.30232558],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.12121212,  0.87878788],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.97727273,  0.02272727],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.87878788,  0.12121212],
       [ 0.02380952,  0.97619048],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.10810811,  0.89189189],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.97619048,  0.02380952],
       [ 0.54545455,  0.45454545],
       [ 0.02380952,  0.97619048],
       [ 0.07317073,  0.92682927],
       [ 0.94285714,  0.05714286],
       [ 0.25714286,  0.74285714],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.97560976,  0.02439024],
       [ 0.11111111,  0.88888889],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.02857143,  0.97142857],
       [ 0.97916667,  0.02083333],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.02564103,  0.97435897],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.32258065,  0.67741935],
       [ 0.56410256,  0.43589744],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.92682927,  0.07317073],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.08823529,  0.91176471]])

fr.oob_score_
Out[12]: 0.87

fr.feature_importances_
Out[13]: array([ 0.82407373,  0.17592627])
```